# SQL SERVER Formatear Datos Numericos

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, stored-procedure

He estado probando varias formas, pero nada me sale.

Tengo unos datos en una tabla de `SQL` de tipo `numeric(18,2)` y necesito formatearlos a **dinero** con *signo de dólar*, *comas* y *puntos decimales* para la visualizacion de esos datos en pantalla (`asp.net`).

Quisiera que sea por medio de un `stored procedure` que ya tengo hecho.

Hay uno que es para entrada de datos y otro de salida, para hacer `Update` de ciertos datos, incluyendo los de dinero.

Mi duda mayormente, es que no se en que parte del `stored procedure` ubicar esta linea de codigo `FORMAT(@Parametro, 'c', 'en-US')`

Estoy empezando a trabajar con base de datos.

[image: PARA AGREGAR DATA A LAS TABLAS]
[image: SP PARA UPDATE]

Comment: La respuesta sencilla es: NO LO HAGAS! Debes guardar los números como número y dar formato hasta la capa de visualización (que muy rara vez es directamente el resultad  de la consulta SQL).

Comment: Evita adjuntar imágenes, estas deben ser solo ilustrativas al problema. Edita tu pregunta y adjunta el código 
necesario para entender mejor tu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Pues podrías incluirlos directamente en el <kbd>**INSERT**</kbd>, solo toca reemplazar:

```sql
insert into Servicio
values(@Tablilla,
@ModeloID,
@AñoID,
getdate(),
@DescTrabajo,
format(@labor,'c','en-US'), -- aquí
format(@piezas,'c','en-US'), -- aquí 
format(@total,'c','en-US'), -- y aquí 
@nombre,
@numtel ) 

select 'servicio creado correctamente' as mensaje
```

Para el <kbd>**UPDATE**</kbd>, más de lo mismo:

```sql
update servicio
set tablilla = @tablilla,
modeloid = @modeloid,
añoid = @anioid,
desctrabajo = @desctrabajo,
nombre = @nombre,
numtel = @numtel, 
labor = format(@labor,'c','en-US'), -- aquí
piezas = format(@piezas,'c','en-US'), -- aquí
[total cobrado] = format(@total,'c','en-US'), -- y aquí
where servicioid = @servicio id

select 'los cambios se hicieron correctamente as mensaje
```

> Acotación importante! Las columnas como `año` y `total cobrado` (con espacios) son columnas MUY mal denominadas, te recomendaría echar un ojo a las buenas prácticas en base de datos, desde diseño, modelamiento para luego pasar a la programación y administración.

Comment: Esto probablemente pierda el formato si las columnas son de tipo numérico. Peor aún, generaría un error de incompatibilidad.